# Could we extend the functional $\xi \in C_0^\infty \left( \Omega \right) \to \xi \left( 0 \right) \in \mathbb R$ to a cont functional in Sobolev sp

Tags: sobolev-spaces, dual-spaces

Consider the space of $C_0^\infty \left( \Omega  \right)$ functions where $\Omega =(-1,1)$. Define the functional

$$\phi :\xi  \in C_0^\infty \left( \Omega  \right) \to \xi \left( 0 \right) \in \mathbb R$$

could we extend this functional to a continuous
linear functional on the Sobolev space $H_0^0$ or $H_0^1$ respectively ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, we can extend it to $H^1$, because Sobolev’s lemma says
$$
|u(0)| \leq c\|u\|_{H^1}
\qquad\textrm{for}\quad u\in C^\infty_0(\mathbb{R}),
$$
where $c$ is a constant independent of $u$.
However, note that this is only true in 1 dimension.

For $L^2$ it doesn’t work in any dimension.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132963/discussion-on-answer-by-timur-could-we-extend-the-functional-xi-in-c-0-infty).